# connection closed by remote host by gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I have recently upgraded gerrit version from 2.15.17 to 3.3.0 and now when cloning the repo it hangs with the following message and when `enter` button in the keyboard is pressed the cloning happens

```
 ****    Welcome to Gerrit Code Review    ****

  Hi user, you have successfully connected over SSH.

  Unfortunately, interactive shells are disabled.
  To clone a hosted Git repository, use:

  git clone ssh://user@reviews.example.com:29418/REPOSITORY_NAME.git

Connection to reviews.example.com closed by remote host.
Connection to reviews.example.com closed.
Cloning into 'bin_user'...
```

When checking the gerrit logs it gives the following error

```
[2021-05-24T10:40:46.918Z] [sshd-SshDaemon[1b079e81](port=22)-nio2-thread-6] WARN  org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession : onExit(ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=0]-ServerSessionImpl[user@/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56108]) code=127 message='' SshChannelClosedException closing shell: flush(ChannelOutputStream[ChannelSession[id=0, recipient=0]-ServerSessionImpl[user@/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56108]] SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA) length=0 - stream is already closed
[2021-05-24T10:40:58.922Z] [sshd-SshDaemon[1b079e81](port=22)-nio2-thread-1] WARN  org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSessionImpl : exceptionCaught(ServerSessionImpl[user@/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56108])[state=Opened] IOException: Pipe closed
```

I tried with some settings in gerrit.config file still no luck

Comment: Which command have you executed?

Comment: ssh  -p 29418  $USERNAME@reviews.example.com. When running this command, it hangs and when we press the enter key in keyboard it gives the error ```connection reviews.example.com closed by remote host ```. This is not letting me clone the repo to my local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't log in to the Gerrit server using the 29418 port, you can use the "ssh -p 29418" to the Gerrit server just to check if the connection is working as expected.

To clone a repository you need to execute a "git clone" command like this:

```
git clone ssh://USER@GERRIT-SERVER:29418/REPOSITORY
```

Comment: I am not trying to login to the gerrit server. I am trying to clone the gerrit repository. When trying to clone the repository it gives the error 'connection from remote closed' and hangs. Then I need to press the 'enter' button in the keyboard and then it will start to clone

Comment: I know that... but you said you're using the command "ssh -p 29418 $USERNAME@reviews.example.com". This command is WRONG.  You must use the "git clone" command that I've written in my answer.

Comment: we are using a shell script to clone the repository. That script will first connect to the repo and displays the message as ```Welcome to Gerrit Code Review ``` and then it clone the repo. This was working fine before upgrading to version 3.3.0. After upgrading, it does not display the message ```Welcome to Gerrit Code Review ``` and then hangs. I have also pasted the gerrit error log

Comment: You don't need to "connect" to the Gerrit server (and receive the "Welcome to Gerrit Code Review") to clone the repository. All you need to do is execute the "git clone" command. Anyway, the problem you're relating is an issue that was fixed in the 3.3.4 version. See the Gerrit 3.3.4 Release notes (https://www.gerritcodereview.com/3.3.html#334) and the Issue 11142 (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=11142).

Comment: okay. Thank you for the info. I will modify the shell script to clone only the repo